# mdframed does not split correctly between pages

Tags: page-breaking, mdframed

I use `mdframed` to make boxes and split them across pages. However, sometimes `mdframed` splits! very strangely across the pages. In this example he prefers splitting, while there is enough space to put it all.

[image]

I would like to know where the conflict is. I am not interested to tweaking this example, because I have hundreds of boxes. I need to understand where the problem is and fix it in the whole book at once.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\newcommand{\mytext}{uutien gaaaetlmsl t n.tu aii s liwmuarpulfoaf ealiesnPui sutuacttcuMitai   ibioErertix}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\tikzstyle{titregris} =[draw=gray, thick, fill=white,
  text=black, rectangle,minimum height=0.7cm]
\mdfdefinestyle{Argumentstyle}{}
\begin{document}
${}$ \vspace{18cm}
\begin{mdframed}[style=Argumentstyle,
firstextra={\node[titregris,xshift=5mm] at (P-|O) {puttetuiroe};},]
\begin {enumerate}
\item \mytext \mytext
\item \mytext \mytext
\item \mytext \mytext
\item \mytext \mytext
\item \mytext \mytext
\end {enumerate}
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

UPDATE: I saw that the wrong breakings take place when there is empty space before. `mdframed` seems to calculate the empty space needed, correctly splits the box such that the first part has the right length, but then it starts WRONGLY, ALWAYS, from the beginning of the next page! [image: Here is a screen shot!]

UPDATE 2: I think now that the problem is given by the node that defines the title of the box. Namely, it gives extra height which does not fit into calculations... I changed the present form of the title with the usual one (`frametitlerule=true, frametitle={MyTitle}`), and the problem dissapeared in all the document :) However, I do like the node of the previous form...

UPDATE 3: It seems to be indeed from the title box, which goes up few millimeters and `mdframed` does not take into account for the calculation of available space. The only workaround I found until now was to move the title box INSIDE the main box... I checked, with this the whole document is OK.

Comment: I have a similar problem and am wondering if there's a way to add more space to `mdframed` for the calculation. It seems that a raised title-box (the one I'm using is an example of the documentation) is throwing the page-break calculations offs. `skipabove` and `topinnermargin` do somehow help, but the values need to be very high before it works consistently, leading to ugly spacing.

Comment: @badroit Can you provide more details, e.g. an example that is not working for you.

Comment: @Andrew, the OP's question refers to the same problem I'm having and his MWE fits well. I have a similar situation in a book with lots of such mdframed environments. Your solution to add `skipabove` and `topinnermargin` helps some cases (including the MWE), but for others the `skipabove` and `topinnermargin` need to be set very high ... it seems to be a partial workaround rather than a solution. The core problem specifically seems to be that `mdframed` doesn't take the height of the raised title box into account when calculating the page-break.

Answer (score 4):

You can reserve space for the title block with `skipabove` and `topinnermargin`.  Additionally it turns out that you should hide the size of this title box by setting a bounding box of zero size.  This improves breaking across columns:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twocolumn]{book}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\newcommand{\mytext}{uutien gaaaetlmsl t n.tu aii s liwmuarpulfoaf ealiesnPui sutuacttcuMitai   ibioErertix}

\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\tikzstyle{titregris}=[draw=gray, thick, fill=white,
  text=black, rectangle, minimum height=0.7cm]
\mdfdefinestyle{Argumentstyle}{}

\begin{document}

\vspace*{18cm}

\begin{mdframed}[style=Argumentstyle,
  skipabove={1.2\baselineskip},
  innertopmargin={1.2\baselineskip},
  firstextra={\useasboundingbox (P) rectangle (P); \node[titregris,xshift=5mm] at (P-|O)  {puttetuiroe};},
  singleextra={\useasboundingbox (P) rectangle (P); \node[titregris,xshift=5mm] at (P-|O)  {puttetuiroe};}]
\begin {enumerate}
\item \mytext \mytext
\item \mytext \mytext
\item \mytext \mytext
\item \mytext \mytext
\item \mytext \mytext
\end {enumerate}
\end{mdframed}

\mytext

\begin{mdframed}[style=Argumentstyle,
  skipabove={1.2\baselineskip},
  innertopmargin={1.2\baselineskip},
  firstextra={\useasboundingbox (P) rectangle (P); \node[titregris,xshift=5mm] at (P-|O)  {puttetuiroe};},
  singleextra={\useasboundingbox (P) rectangle (P); \node[titregris,xshift=5mm] at (P-|O)  {puttetuiroe};}]
\begin {enumerate}
\item \mytext \mytext
\item \mytext \mytext
\item \mytext \mytext
\item \mytext \mytext
\item \mytext \mytext
\end {enumerate}
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

Incidentally, note the use of `\vspace*` rather than `${}$ \vspace`.  The star `*` means that the space is not to be discarded at page boundaries etc.

With `\vspace*{20cm}` the output is:

[image: Second output]

Comment: Note that this solution doesn't work if you set vspace to 18cm (per the OP) rather than 20cm.

Comment: Setting a bounding box of zero size fixes this.  I have updated my answer.

Comment: Okay, this works thanks! The next problem, however, is that if the example appears at the top of the page, the title-box pops above the top margin.

Comment: @badroit You could add `outerlinewidth=0.35cm,outerlinecolor=white`, but this will also make environment narrow.  I don't if that is acceptable.