# Mdframed: negative top margin with page break skips a page

Tags: page-breaking, mdframed

I am using the development version (1.9d) of the mdframed package to customize the proof environment in the following way. I wish that a line runs down from the word "Proof." and that the text of the proof is indented accordingly. To do that, I used a mdframed environment with only the left edge visible and a negative top margin (see MWE below). However, when a page break is needed, the environment starts on a new page every time.

The situation is very similar to [Split mdframed environment occasionally skips page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114829/split-mdframed-environment-occasionally-skips-page?rq=1) and [mdframed does not split correctly between pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135083/mdframed-does-not-split-correctly-between-pages?rq=1). However, the first question provides only a solution when the "overhead text" is obtained with Tikz, and the solution provided in the second (using skipabove) does not seem to work in my case.

I have toyed with the options skipabove, splitbottomskip, splittopskip, and adding more spaces with beforebreak, without success.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsfonts,lipsum, mdframed}

\newmdenv[hidealllines=true,leftline=true,linewidth=1.5pt,innerleftmargin = 10pt,
innertopmargin=-1.1\baselineskip]{np}
\newenvironment{niceproof}{
  \hangindent5pt\hangafter0
  \begin{np}\hspace{-15pt}\textit{Proof.}~}
  {\hfill$\square$\end{np}}

\begin{document}
If it fits in one page, everything works as intended.
\begin{niceproof}
 \lipsum[1-4] 
\end{niceproof}
\clearpage{}
But if we add a little more text, it starts on the next page 
(even though the box is cut in two properly):
\begin{niceproof}
\lipsum[1-5] 
\end{niceproof}
\end{document}
```

If this way of customizing the proof environment is not recommended, I am open to any alternative suggestions. In particular, I would be glad if such a result is possible by using only a newmdenv.

Edit: result after compilation of the MWE. As you can see, the first Proof environment displays properly, but the second skips a page before displaying, although the break is good (I did not show page 4, which contains the rest of the Lorem Ipsum).

[result after compilation of the MWE http://www.latp.univ-mrs.fr/~hellouin/Capture.png](http://www.latp.univ-mrs.fr/~hellouin/Capture.png)

Comment: can you add a printscreen of what you observe?

Comment: I did  it, but I'm afraid it's not very readable. The grey line in page 3 has been eaten by the png commpression.