# mdframed and spurious page breaks

Tags: page-breaking, mdframed

I don't know why but mdframed sometimes introduce some page breaks for no apparent reason. Is there a way to prevent mdframed from inserting these page breaks ? I cannot do a minimal working example, it is not repeatable (I do not understand how it happens). Here is an example, there is a page break in exercize 7.12 before the sentence "... and give their nature..."

[image: spurious page break within mdframe]

the latex code that generates the page is

```
\begin{exercise}
For each value of $\beta$, give the critical points of the function:
\[f(x,y)=x^{2}+y^{2}+\beta xy +x +2y\]
and give their nature (min/max, local/global) ?
\end{exercise}
```

The environment exercise is defined elsewhere by:

```
\newmdenv[
frametitlefont=\color{ocre}\bfseries\normalfont,
frametitleaboveskip=-6pt,
rightline=false,
leftline=true,
topline=false,
bottomline=false,
linecolor=ocre,
backgroundcolor=ocre!5,
linewidth=2pt,
]{exoBox}

\newenvironment{exercise}[1][]{%
\refstepcounter{exo}
\ifstrempty{#1}%
{\begin{exoBox}[frametitle={\colorbox{white}{\space Exercize \theexo \space}}]\noindent}
{\begin{exoBox}[frametitle={\colorbox{white}{\space Exercize \theexo : #1\space}}]\noindent}
} %
{\end{exoBox}}
```

I have no clue to why these pagebreaks happen, if you have any hint on what I should do to analyse the problem (and hopefully solve it at the end of the day), I would be very grateful. Thank you

Comment: Use the tcolorbox package, it's breakable code is much more reliable.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: Similar question: [page breaking - How to prevent mdframed from typesetting a widow line that contains just a bit vspace with colored background? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241543/how-to-prevent-mdframed-from-typesetting-a-widow-line-that-contains-just-a-bit-v)

Comment: Suspected duplicate of [mdframed does not split correctly between pages - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135083/mdframed-does-not-split-correctly-between-pages)